# Don't Loop, Iterate! (Common Lisp)

Tags: loops, for-loop, common-lisp

I'm having trouble switching to an iterate version of some loop code:

```
(defun get-bound-?vars-1 (tree)
  (loop for item in tree
        when (consp item)
          if (member (car item) '(exists forall doall))
            nconc (delete-if-not #'?varp
                    (alexandria:flatten (second item)))
            else nconc (get-bound-?vars item)))
```

My corresponding iterate translation:

```
(defun get-bound-?vars-2 (tree)
  (iter (for item in tree)
        (when (consp item)
          (if (member (car item) '(exists forall doall))
            (nconc (delete-if-not #'?varp
                     (alexandria:flatten (second item))))
            (nconc (get-bound-?vars item))))))
```

As test case:

```
(defparameter *tree* 
  '(if (exists (?t transmitter)
         (and (connecting ?t ?connector)
              (bind (color ?t $hue))))
     (if (not (exists ((?t1 ?t2) transmitter)
                (and (connecting ?t1 ?connector)
                     (connecting ?t2 ?connector)
                     (bind (color ?t1 $hue1))
                     (bind (color ?t2 $hue2))
                     (not (eql $hue1 $hue2)))))
       (activate-connector! ?connector $hue))))
```

Then loop OK:

```
(get-bound-?vars-1 *tree*) => (?T ?T1 ?T2)
```

But iterate not OK:

```
(get-bound-?vars-2 *tree*) => NIL
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I think you need `nconcing` instead of `nconc`, https://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/doc/Accumulations.html

Comment: @npostavs Yes, that's it. Perplexing that the hardest thing to see is in front of my nose. Thanks.